# How can I add a command to the Visual Studio toolbar to switch between source control plug ins?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-addins

I'm working with several different solutions, some of which use tfs and some which use svn.  I would like to add a button in the toolbar to switch between providers instead of having to go through the "options" menu. 
How can this be done?
Note: [source control switcher](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2264/Sourcecode-Control-Switcher) doesn't work with VS2013
[image: sample toolbar]

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be any direct way to add the command "Current source control plugin" to the toolbar, via toolbar customization.

Maybe a Visual studio extension could be written for this.